# Getting value from react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component `InputArea` with `state = {input: ''}`

Then I map several of these components in a container and write them in `state = {inputAreas: []}`

Now, how can I get inputs in the container? Logging `this.state.inputAreas[0]` returns object like this:

> {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: ƒ, key: "1", ref: null, props:
>   {…}, …}

In elements it shows like this:

> `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="input" value="abc">`

Using this.state.prefooterArea[0].value gives undefined.

I also tried passing input from component to container as props, but it says `getInput is not a function`. From what I understood it has something to do with the fact I used map in the container. I can't use redux in this project.

Code of component

```
class PrefooterAreaInput extends Component {
  state = {
    input: ''
  }

  textChangedHandler = (event) => {
    let newState = {};
    newState[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(newState);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          type="text"
          name="input"
          value = {this.state.input}
          onChange={this.textChangedHandler}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Code of container

```
class DescriptionFrame extends Component {
  state = {,
    prefooterArea: [<PrefooterAreaInput key={1}/>]
  };

  addFooterInputHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.prefooterArea.length < prefooterInputFieldsMax) {
      var newPrefooterArea = this.state.prefooterArea.map(
        inputField => inputField
      );
      newPrefooterArea.push(
        <PrefooterAreaInput key={this.state.prefooterArea.length + 1} />
      );
      this.setState({ prefooterArea: newPrefooterArea });
    }
  };

  removeFooterInputHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.prefooterArea.length > 1) {
      var newPrefooterArea = this.state.prefooterArea.map(
        inputField => inputField
      );
      newPrefooterArea.splice(newPrefooterArea.length - 1);
      this.setState({ prefooterArea: newPrefooterArea });
    }
  render() {
    // want to get this.state.prefooterArea[0]'s value 
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.prefooterArea}
          <a
            className="nav-link"
            href=""
            onClick={this.addFooterInputHandler}
          >
            Add More
          </a>
          <a
            className="nav-link"
            href=""
            onClick={this.removeFooterInputHandler}
          >
            Remove Last
          </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in details what are you trying to accomplish? Provide more information

Comment: I am trying to get input value in the container. There is a list of components in container's state, each component stores input in it's own state.

Comment: But why are you referencing whole element, why don't you store just input values?

Comment: @MarioNikolaus true. And is `key` a prop? then only you can add it as attribute on custom component. Because that(`PrefooterAreaInput`) is not built in component as of `JSX.HTMLElement` category. No need of assigning `value` attr in input to `this.state.input`.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. This caused problem.

```
prefooterArea: [<PrefooterAreaInput key={1}/>]
```

I should have added that initial PrefooterAreaInput with lifecycle method instead. With that I was able to pass state just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve something like this ?

child component :

```
export default class InputBox extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
            <input onChange={event => this.props.onChange(event.target.value)} />

    );
}}
```

parent component :

```
   import InputBox from './InputBox';

    class FilterBar extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                inputs: "" //get input value from state this  input
            };
           this.updateFilters = this.updateFilters.bind(this);
        }

       updateFilters(i) {
           this.setState({ inputs: i }); // this will print whatever input you type
       }

        render() {
           return (
             <div>
                 <InputBox onChange={(i) => this.updateFilters(i)} />
             </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, something like that. I'll edit my post to include more code.

Comment: Done. The whole file was just too big, so I had to crop relevant code.

Comment: can u explain what's your input and expected output like input's value will be shown while click addFooterInputHandler, will be removed after removeFooterInputHandler ?

I can see that you set PrefooterAreaInput  component as a sate in DescriptionFrame , It's not advisable to have a component in state

Comment: If you want to pass input value from child to parent component react

try like this in your child:

                <input onChange={event => this.props.onChange(event.target.value)} {...otherProps} />

Comment: My input is whatever I type in. As I said, I tried passing input from child as props, but it says "is not a function"

Comment: changed my answer, please check it. Passed input from child to parent through props as a function. For demo added this https://react-zowwmt.stackblitz.io